# How to allow guests to add items to cart before logging in or registration using laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am not well conversant with laravel 4 but am trying out.
How can I allow guests to add items to cart before login or registration, then keep their content on login in laravel 4.2?

This is my carts table

```
Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('quantity');
        $table->string('total');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    });
```

My users table

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();           
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
        $table->string('confirmation_code')->nullable();
        $table->string('password',60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

CartController is as below

```
$buyer = Auth::user()->id;
    $product_id = Input::get('product_id');
$quantity = Input::get('quantity');
$product = Product::find((int)$product_id); 
$total_price = $product->price * $quantity; 
$count = Cart::where('product_id','=',$product_id)
    ->where('user_id','=',$buyer)->count();
if ($count)
 {
    return Redirect::back()->with('error','The product already exists in the cart');
    } 
  Cart::create([
    'user_id'=>$buyer,
    'product_id'=>$product_id,
    'quantity'=>$quantity,
    'total'=>$total_price
    ]);
```

Anyone with an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why tagging xcode?

Comment: What have you actually tried to overcome this problem? If you really think about this problems there are many many ways to solve it and it just comes down to thinking logically.

You could create a temporary guest user so you have a user_id that can then be used in the carts table.

You could hold the cart data in a users session which then gets saved to the carts table once the user has signed up.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to use sessions and i got right, thanks
you can follow [laravel.com/docs/4.2/session](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session)